# Use greek letters in adding annotation in convert imagemagick

Tags: label, symbols, imagemagick-convert

I need to annotate some label/text containing greek letters on a figure using `convert` from imagemagick on linux.
What is the best option?

Trivial choices such as:

```
ii=1
label="α β $ii"
convert in.png -fill black -annotate "$label" out.png
```

won't work.
I am not familiar with font coding options.

Answer (score 1):

One way that works for me in ImageMagick 6.9.9.23 Mac OSX Sierra is to use a Greek font. (The symbol font also works)

```
ii=1
label="a b $ii"
convert logo: -font GreekMathSymbols -pointsize 64 -gravity center -fill red -annotate +0+0 "$label" out.png
```

[image]

Alternately, use a UTF-8 compatible text editor and type your text using a font that supports those characters. For example I put your alpha beta one characters into a text file using the same GreekMathSymbols font.

[image]

Then

```
convert logo: -font GreekMathSymbols -pointsize 64 -gravity center -fill red -annotate +0+0 "@greek.txt" out2.png
```

[image]

See also http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode

Comment: Thanks, option #1 worked on linux with: `-font Symbol`